# Can a person earn Peer Pressure badge more than once?

Tags: support, badges

Is a person eligible to earn the badge peer pressure more than once, if he deletes more than one question with score less than -3?

Comment: Considering to "sit it out" next time you get a downvote? ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Peer Pressure can be awarded only once per site.

There are other badges which have "This badge can be awarded multiple times." beside their description.  These can be awarded multiple times. E.g Good Answer, Great Question, Necromancer etc.,

[image]

We do not want you to post which receive a score of -3 or less and delete. So, earning once is more than enough.